# Firebase Database Not in Sync

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to keep the addToCart button in sync with the Firebase database. The button should be enabled if the checkForActiveOrdersQuery has no children, otherwise, it should be disabled.
The issue with the below code is that the keepSynced(true) is not working.

```
checkForActiveOrders = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("activeOrders");
    checkForActiveOrdersQuery = checkForActiveOrders.child(restaurantID).child(tableID);
    checkForActiveOrdersQuery.keepSynced(true);
    checkForActiveOrdersQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String orderIDKey = dataSnapshot1.getKey();

                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {

                    addToCartButton.setEnabled(true);

                } else if (!orderIDKey.equals(orderID)){

                    addToCartButton.setEnabled(false);

                } else if (orderIDKey.equals(orderID)) {

                    addToCartButton.setEnabled(true);

                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `addValueEventListener` instead `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

Comment: Do you get the desired behavior when using `addValueEventListener()`?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes.. the behaviour is working fine.. but the issue is with the realtime syncing with the database.
I need to refresh the app to reflect the changes

Comment: @Ticherhaz yes.. I tried.. the behaviour is working fine.. its the realtime syncing that is not working as expected..

Comment: @mayur What kind of view are you using to display the data?

Comment: @AlexMamo.. i have found out the solution.. I added a dataSnapshot.exists() condition before the for each loop, and it worked.. :)